# asp:login does not redirect after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

Scenario: 
Visitors enter the "enter.aspx" page, which they have to be authorized to enter, so they'll be redirected to login page with address of "enter.aspx" in querystring. but after user name and pass word is enterd and login process is done, Form dosn't redirect visitors to enter.aspx again.

[Here you can see it](http://www.ajorak.ir/userpanel/enter.aspx)

For test you can use:

username:   v@yahoo.com

password:   v@yahoo.com

and here is relative part of web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="http://www.ajorak.ir/users/signin.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" timeout="30">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
  <location path="userpanel" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
      <trust level="Full" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

What did i forget?

Comment: In CS page you need to mention where to redirect after validating user for e.g. `Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx");`

Comment: For Test you must know Arabic!!! :P